# How to generate jUnit Tests dynamically based on Data

Tags: android, testing, junit

I`m trying to make tests dynamically.
Here is a sample solution

http://jorgemanrubia.net/2008/09/18/generating-junit-test-cases-dynamically/

that is not working for android. But I`m looking for similar for android.
When i used above example just nothing happens, no test is run.

Comment: That example will run no tests if the directory is empty. Are you sure there are files? Have you tried debugging this in a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the point in test case generation. You can just write parametrized test which will run the same test over each parameter you provide. Take a look at corresponding documentation for JUnit framework https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests .